# 2 Rows with 4 divs each can't seem to position them like example Answered

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to position 4 divs in a row, but in a way that when I click one of the divs and it expands with some information, it should push the bottom one down. The classes of the 8 divs are the same. I tried with display: inline-block, but when one of the divs expands, all the bottom 4 divs go down. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

After the click, and the div expand it should be this:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

So here is the code on how I did this using php. I needed to do this in Wordpress, so the code is basically a Wordpress code.

```
get_header('home'); ?>

    <?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'the_teams', 'posts_per_page' => 9999);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
$n=0;?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$n++;
if ($n == 1):?>
<div class="block-wrapper"> 
<?php endif;

if ($n < 3):?>
<div class="team<?php echo $n;?>">
<div class="holder">
<div class="line1"></div>
<div class="title"><?php echo the_title();?></div>
<div class="line2"></div>
</div>

<div class="image"><img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" /></div>
<div class="text"><?php echo get_field("short_description"); ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif;    

if ($n ==2):
    $n=0; ?>
</div>  
<?php endif; ?>


<?php
endwhile;
endif;
?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So what I did here is that I made the code execute the  4 times. I have 8 posts, each green square is a post. So the  will be created 4 times, and inside of it php will drop
 and , after that it will start all over. Here is the html

```
<div class="block-wrapper"> 
<div class="team1">
<div class="holder">
<div class="line1"></div>
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="line2"></div>
</div>

<div class="image"><img src=""></div>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>


<div class="team2">
<div class="holder">
<div class="line1"></div>
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="line2"></div>
</div>

<div class="image"><img src=""></div>
<div class="text"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This code prints 4 times making 4 columns. After that you want to set display: inline-block to block-wrapper and set some margin right property and you are good to go. Hope it helps.

Comment: Calling out other users is not a useful part of an answer.